# access data from CommandLineRunner in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, command-line, controller

In my command Line runner

```
@Controller
public class HelloController implements CommandLineRunner {

    static List<todos> todos;
  @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
//todos.add(...)
   }
```

In a second controller class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/list-todos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showTodos(ModelMap model) throws IOException {
// I would access to the list of TODOs defined in HelloController 
    return "list-todos";
}
```

My question is how can I  access to the list of TODOs defined in HelloController from showTodos (in TODOController.java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be better to use a Spring bean instead of using a static List for a use case like this.

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig() {

    @Bean
    public List<todos> todos() {
        List<todos> todos = new ArrayList<>();
        //todos.add(...)
    }
}

@Controller
public class SecondController {

    @Autowired
    private List<todos> todos;  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/list-todos", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showTodos(ModelMap model) throws IOException {

        // Use todos 

        return "list-todos";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thak you I'm using a CommandLineRunner before application starts to add todos not in a bean. Then I m trying to use this data within the application

Comment: I know that you are using a CommandLineRunner but you should use a bean instead of a static reference in a controller. This is not how the CommandLineRunner should be used.

Comment: Can you please edit you answer with a commandline runner because I didn't undrestand? I will be so grateful and thankful